# Scrollable Footer in lightning:map

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am implementing a lightning:map and was following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/example) documentation. If you go to Complex Example you can see that the footer/sidebar has a scroll bar and limits the map component to a set dimension.

In my implementation, the sidebar is not scrollable and it causes the map to extend down to fit every record as seen below.

[image]

There is no information on this documentation or that I could find on Google. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messed around with the css for a while. Had to add a max height and width for slds-coordinates, which is the class of the footer.

```
.THIS .slds-coordinates{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
max-height: 41.25rem;
max-width: 20rem;
}
```