# Unable to apply css in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

Below css not applying to my lwc map component. How to apply css to slds-coordinates?

I see it's working in aura. How to apply the same to lwc?

[Scrollable Footer in lightning:map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238775/scrollable-footer-in-lightningmap)

css

```css
    .slds-coordinates{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-height: 41.25rem !important;
        max-width: 20rem !important;
        color:red;
    }
```

html

```html
    <lightning-map 
            map-markers={mapMarkers}
            markers-title={markersTitle}
    list-view=true></lightning-map>
```

js

```js
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class LightningExampleMapMultipleMarkers extends LightningElement {
        mapMarkers = [
            {
                location: {
                    City: "Cap-d'Ail",
                    Country: 'France',
                },
    
                icon: 'custom:custom26',
                title: "Cap-d'Ail",
            },
            {
                location: {
                    City: 'Beaulieu-sur-Mer',
                    Country: 'France',
                },
    
                icon: 'custom:custom96',
                title: 'Beaulieu-sur-Mer',
            },
            {
                location: {
                    City: 'Sainte-Maxime',
                    Country: 'France',
                },
    
                icon: 'custom:custom92',
                title: 'Sainte-Maxime',
            },
        ];
        markersTitle = "Côte d'Azur";
    }
```

@muenzpraeger any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that overriding CSS of standard components can only be done by uploading a CSS file as a Static Resource and then load the Static Resource in the component.

Comment: I didnt find documentation for this - can you pls put the link if there is documentation? if there is no documentation, this may break anytime in future releases

Comment: To expand upon this a little bit, if @RavichandraSatti adds a custom CSS file for his component, because of the way different component's DOMs are isolated from one another, his parent company has _no access_ to style the `lightning-map` component that is a child of his parent component. CSS on components is scoped to the component it is a part of.